# Need to click two time on the browser back-button to going back after reload with keycloak-js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, browser, react-router, keycloak

I have a Vite.js project to which I've added Keycloak authentication using the keycloak-js library. Everything works except for a small UX issue.

Example: when I'm on "/home," navigate to "/users," and then reload the page, the Keycloak authentication using the init() method restarts. When I try to go back, the browser history takes me back to the authentication URL and redirects me again to the same "/users" page. I have to double-click the back button to return to "/home." How can I achieve normal behavior without the need for a double-click?

My keycloak init code :

```
keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).then((authenticated) => {
  if (authenticated) {
  } else {
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Keycloak initialization error', error);
});
```

My Home component :

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
   const {keycloakAuthService} = useContext(ServiceContext);
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   return (
       <div>
           <button onClick={keycloakAuthService.Logout}>Logout</button>
           <button onClick={() => navigate('/users')}>test</button>
           <p>Bonjour ..</p>
       </div>
   )
}
```

My App component :

```
function App() {

   const {keycloakAuthService} = useContext(ServiceContext);
   const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(keycloakAuthService.isAuthenticated);

   useEffect(() => {
       keycloakAuthService.Init().then(() => setIsAuthenticated(keycloakAuthService.isAuthenticated));
   }, [keycloakAuthService]);

   return (
   <>
       {!isAuthenticated && <GlobalLoader />}
       {isAuthenticated && (
           <BrowserRouter>
               <Routes>
                   <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
                   <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
                   <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} /> 
                   <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
               </Routes>
           </BrowserRouter>
       )}
   </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Where does your code issue the forward navigation, i.e. the PUSH action, to the `"/users"` route? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that includes all the relevant routing and navigation code.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with how keycloak navigates to the admin portal and back to the app, it is *adding* a history entry instead of redirecting there and back so your history stack is maintained how you want. I'm unfamiliar with keycloak though and didn't see any settings to configure this behavior using a quick google search.